# custom series order in dygraphs legend

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have this series in my csv:

Date,color,pressure,air
23.12.1912,green,1090,good
...

Dygraph displays them in the legend in the order as they are in the csv but
can this be resorted to "Date,air,color,pressure" without reordering
the whole csv file?

Answer (score -1):

Import csv to javascript and reorder what You want.